# How to use ng-repeat to display according to starting letter of item values

Tags: angularjs

I have an array with items names ranging from A-Z.
What I want to do is `ng-repeat` for each letter of the alphabet.

For A letters in Array:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: 'item_name'">
   {{item.item_name}}
</div>
```

For B letters in Array:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: 'item_name'">
   {{item.item_name}}
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to print each letter in a single line from A to Z?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with `custom filter`

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:criteriaMatch('z')"> 
   {{item.name}}
</div>

 <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:criteriaMatch('A')"> 
   {{item.name}}
</div>
```

and `filter` function like below

```
$scope.criteriaMatch = function(x) {
    return function( item ) {
        return item.name.startsWith(x);
    };
};
```

here is **[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mr_7/s2Lozusc/)**

hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `groupBy` filter using the [`angular.filter` module](//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | groupBy: 'item_name.substr(0,1)'">
   {{item.item_name}}
</div>
```

Comment: I see. I did the install and it shows some functionality. Except for the fact that item_names won't display.